# EF Code First creating obsolete column?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have the following classes that I use for my database:

```
public abstract class BaseProduct
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(100), Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(10000), Display(Name = "Product Description"), DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string ImagePath { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Price")]
    public double? UnitPrice { get; set; }

    public int? CategoryID { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

    public string Author { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PriceRelation> Prices { get; set; }
}
[Table("Packages")]
public class Package : BaseProduct
{
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
[Table("Products")]
public class Product : BaseProduct
{
    public virtual ICollection<Package> Packages { get; set; }
}
public class Category
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(100), Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Category Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int? ParentID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ParentID")]
    public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Category> Children { get; set; } 

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }

}
```

And this is the model builder:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Package>().HasMany(p => p.Products).WithMany(p => p.Packages)
            .Map(m =>
                {
                    m.ToTable("PackageRelations");
                    m.MapLeftKey("PackageID");
                    m.MapRightKey("ProductID");
                });
    }
    }
```

It sets up the relations as I want to, in the following way:

Table: BaseProducts
Columns: ID, ProductName, Description, ImagePath, UnitPrice, CategoryID, Author

Table: Packages
Columns: ID

Table: Products
Columns: ID, Category_CategoryID

The thing I'm wondering is, why does it create the column Category_CategoryID in the products table? When I populate the table, all the values in this column are null, so it doesn't look like it's being used for anything.

Also, it doesn't seem to have the relations right - because the virtual collection of Products on the category is always empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! The virtual ICollection in the category was of the type Product, when in fact it should be BaseProduct.

It makes sense that the Product would get an extra column to reference the Category when it has that reference for only that type.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to renamed CategoryID to CategoryId so EF can recognize it as a key field for Category entity.

Comment: That didn't fix it. I've added some more information to the original post, as I've found another side-effect from this issue.

Comment: I would suggest using a different concret class called "PackageRelation" and add references to your classes instead of relying on EF to do that. Of course if that is a possibility. I found from experience that Many to Many mapping doesn't work well in all cases and adding a separate class allows greater flexibility if you want for instance to add sorting and such.

Comment: That was the first approach I used, but it didn't give me as easy access to the related objects (virtual properties with lazy load). I don't see how sorting is easier, could you provide an example?

Comment: Let say you need to display products for a package in a particular order. There is no way to accomplish this when using auto generated intersect table. In case of new class called "PackageRelations" you can simply add a new field called "SortOrder" that solves that for you.